# Validating Cart everytime i add something, different amounts each time

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i am new to both php and worldpress and i am doing a validation code for a Ecommerce site and i managed to do this

```
function so_validate_add_cart_item( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, 
$variation_id = '', $variations= '' ) 
{
if ( 1 != 3 ){
 $passed = false;
 wc_add_notice( __( 'You can not do that', 'textdomain' ), 'error' );
}
 return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 
'so_validate_add_cart_item', 10, 5 );
```

the thing is, this is just a generic thing(it doesnt even have a cart amount in it, its just a failure to test)  but my system has a step by step "create your own pack" and each step has a different amount of items that you have to select, so i need to know how i do a check with different conditions in everystep, meaning how do i tell the site to do something in one page and something in another

Comment: You will have to get [Woocomerce composite products](https://woocommerce.com/products/composite-products/) or something like [Gravity forms](https://www.gravityforms.com/) + [woocommerce products addon](https://woocommerce.com/products/gravity-forms-add-ons/) …

Comment: @LoicTheAztec oh i see i was hoping for a free solution but i will see about it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for all cart items details including quantity of each item you can access cart data from global $woocommerce

```
function so_validate_add_cart_item( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, 
$variation_id = '', $variations= '' ) 
{
    global $woocommerce;
    $cart_items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    //enter code here
    if ( 1 != 3 ){
      $passed = false;
      wc_add_notice( __( 'You can not do that', 'textdomain' ), 'error' );
    }
    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 
'so_validate_add_cart_item', 10, 5 );
```

hope this helps.

Comment: what i need to do is to check the cart several times depending of what step of the "create your own pack" i am, meaning in part 1 of the process i need to have 1 item in the cart, so i need to check that the user only puts 1 item in the cart, part 2 its 2 items, so i need to check that the user put 2 items into the cart in that step (or 3 in total) and so on, the complication is that i dont know how to ask for the check to be made at each step, i can write the conditions but i dont know how to tell it to check at a certain page

Comment: hey there, i managed to do something with that code, but i would like to lock that to just a some pages of the site not all of it, do you know what i mean? i can validate it now but i want to be able to buy whatever amout of items outside of the "build your own pack"  part, how would i do that?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you as I don't know what is "build your won pack" or any details about it.

Comment: no problem, you helped me very much, just managed to do it by myself,  just needed to add a condition with a is_page()